# .NET: Create an endpoint that looks like a directory, and accepts an anonymous HTTP PUT verb

Tags: .net

Two fold question:

a) Create, using C# and .NET 4.51, an endpoint that looks like a directory, not a file. E.g. http:///directory/

b) Enable this code to accept an anonymous HTTP PUT  (that it will then save to file, but I just need to see it catching the PUT payload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer looks to be: Create a custom http module, and enable webdav and you are there. Very very little code. The module catches the http request coming in to iis, catches the incoming PUT payload, does basic auth to IIS and writes out the payload.

I have this working, and it is fine.